# jQuery events on iOS 5

Tags: jquery, ios, touchstart

I'm having an issue with jQuery 1.6.4, iOS 5 and the registration of touchstart/touchend events (as stated in the title, obviously).

Take the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mmpa/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $body = $('body');
            $('<button>').html('test jQuery').bind('touchstart', function() { alert('touchstart'); }).appendTo($body);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button ontouchstart="alert('touchstart');">test pure JS</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The "pure JS" button shows the alert in iOS 4.3 and iOS 5, but the "jQuery" button only works on iOS 4.3.
Tested on iPad/iPhone simulator, 4.3 and 5 ; also tested on real iPhone 4.3, iPhone 5.0, and iPad 5.0.
Same reaction if I use a `<input type="button">` or even a simple `<a>` instead of a `<button>`.

Is it a problem related to jQuery as I believe?

Comment: do not use bind('touchstart') and ontouchstart="". Use one of them, and prefer not using inline javascript.

Comment: That was a proof of concept to show that inline JS works when jQuery doesn't. Of course I never, ever use inline JS in real code.

Comment: I was able to produce this error with jQ 1.5.2 and the click event, so perhaps you should modify the title to be something like "jQuery Events on iOS 5"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answered by a guy on Apple dev forums: I need to bind() only *after* the element has been added to the DOM, like so:

```
var btn = $('<a>').html('test jQuery').appendTo($body);
btn.bind('touchstart', function(e) { alert('touchstart'); });
```

Comment: What happens if you use live() instead of bind()? Any explanation for why it stopped working in iOS 5?