# jQuery in iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, safari

Very simple jQuery doesn't work in Safari for iPhone and iPod touch. I make a simplified case:

```
$(function(){
  $("#boto").click(function() {
    $("#boto2").fadeOut("slow");
  });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vWfNj/

http://www.mig-marketing.com/proves2/3.html

It works in computers, it works in iPad but not in my iPod touch. I'm so surprised, I don't understand. Does jQuery needs anything special for Safari in iPhone?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery is related.

Comment: Works on your iPad but not your iPod Touch? Surprising, the Webkit engine is exactly the same on both. What iOS version do they run?

Comment: Also, try enabling the console in Preferences > Safari > Developer. You could be able to see an error dropped there that could point you to where it hangs.

Comment: First of all, iOS *does* have a click event. People say that it doesn't all the time and it's silly. Without a click event, half the sites on the web wouldn't work on iPhone. Second, your sample works on iOS 5 on an iPhone. Have you upgraded to iOS5 on your iPod? I can't see why that would make a difference, but you could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the only problem is with the hosted jQuery library from Google. I don't understand why my iPod touch can download the page but not the jQuery library. I don't know if it is a problem in all iPhones and iPod touch...

Anyway If I download the jQuery library, it works fine. And of course the click function works in the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

The iphone doesnt have a click event, it has a touch event try this.

```
$('.class').bind('touchend', function () {
//Code
});
```

Edit : No idea what your comment means but here....

```
$(function(){
  $("#boto").bind('touchend', function () {
    $("#boto2").fadeOut("slow");
  });
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. But I try this and it doesn't work: http://www.mig-marketing.com/proves2/3.1.html

Comment: @Pino - mobile Safari **does** have a [click event](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html), otherwise it would be a pretty awful experience using it on the web. A touch fires a mousedown, mouseup, then a click, just like a left mouse button.

Comment: It doesn't work. Perhaps my library is not right?: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that on iOS 5, your `#boto` has to be inserted into the DOM *before* you attach event handlers to it. I had a similar problem a few days ago : [jQuery events on iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689004/jquery-events-on-ios-5)

Comment: I don't understand. How I insert the div in the DOM? Anyway I tried in a 4.2.1 version and it doesn't work either

Comment: `$("<div>").appendTo($(body)).bind("touchend", …)` => do the `appendTo` BEFORE the `bind`.

Comment: In your case, your elements are already hard-coded in your HTML file, so as you don't create them on-the-fly, my warning is pointless. They are already in the DOM when your script runs.

Answer (score 0):

try using `.touch` instead of `.click` as a touch event is fired when you click on Any touch supporting device.

Comment: Also see the [Link](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/detecting-iphone-touch-events)